# Haskell Top Level Functions

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell file open on the left side of my screen and ghci on the other half. I want to add functions to the file, save, and experiment with them in ghci. The problem is that I'm not totally sure how to declare top level functions. I'm not even sure I know what top level functions are. I figure they are just functions at the highest level of scope. So my question is what is the minimalist way to do this? For example...

```
let f1 x = x
```

What boilerplate code do I need to surround this with to make it compile so I can load it in ghci?

Comment: I wish you would have made that the answer so I could give the an answer and a vote up. Thanks though! That did the trick

Comment: You should seriously consider setting up Haskell mode and related bits in emacs. It's a bit annoying to get it all working, but once you do, you can get really quick feedback on syntax errors, type errors, style problems caught by HLint, and of course GHCi (preferably cabal repl) on the side.

Comment: I get that with VIM right now. Using Tmux + Vim. I'm sure emacs is great, I see a lot of good devs using it. But I can't afford the time right now to switch editors again. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need more boilerplate, but less! Just don't put the `let` in - that's used for GHCI, not for .hs files. It's also nice to add type annotations in source files, even though those are usually omitted in GHCI.

```
f1 :: a -> a
f1 x = x
```